# At the telephone: "Allô", "está lá", "estou sim", "sim", or ...?

Tags: vocabulário, estrangeirismos, fenômeno-linguístico

How do Portuguese speakers answer the phone?

[**Hello**](https://www.quora.com/Was-Hello-the-name-of-Alexander-Graham-Bells-wife) was supposedly used for the first time around 1877:

> The word "hello," it appears, came straight from the fertile brain of
>   the wizard of Menlo Park, N.J., who concocted the sonorous syllables
>   to resolve one of the first crises of techno-etiquette: **What do you**
>   **say to start a telephone conversation?**

Some attribute [*hello*'s origin](https://www.quora.com/Was-Hello-the-name-of-Alexander-Graham-Bells-wife) to a derived form of *hola*. However, I don't remember hearing native Portuguese speakers saying *olá* in order to start a telephone conversation (not as the first word at least).

These are the expressions I have heard so far from Brazilian people:

- allô?
- oi!
- [organization's name] bom dia/boa tarde/boa noite

And from Portuguese people:

- está lá? (I'm assuming it means: "are you there?")
- estou sim? (this one I'm not sure, does it mean "I am here, yes?"?)
- sim?
- allô (not as often as Brazilian people though)
- [organization's name] bom dia/boa tarde/boa noite

If there are more expressions besides these ones, I would like to know where they are used (locations/regions) and their context.

Finally, why is the [French word "allô"](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/all%C3%B4) used in Portuguese?

Comment: [Tou xim?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3B4c7Jl0_qE)

Comment: The Priberam dictionary says that [alô comes from English](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/al%C3%B4), and not from French.

Comment: @ANeves interestingly [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hallo) mentions that _hallo_ (from where the [Portuguese alô](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/al%C3%B4) derived) is «a variant of _hollo_, itself variant of earlier _holla_ < Middle French _hola_ = _ho_ **ahoy** + _la_ **there**» (1560–70). Current Portuguese pronunciation of _alô_ has a closer phonetic similarity to the French _allô_ than the English _hello_.

Comment: From french influence, several french words are used, such as "garage" (adapted to "garagem"), "chauffage" (car heating), or "chauffeur" (used informaly and adapted to "chôfer").

Comment: "Alô" has only one "l".

Answer (score 4):

Tenho uma tia que quando atende o telefone diz "Pronto" e também já ouvi pessoas atendendo falando "Pois não?".

Aqui no Brasil - São Paulo, quase todo mundo atende dizendo "Alô" como padrão, "Alô?" quando olha no celular e vê um número desconhecido, e algo mais amistoso e às vezes com gírias quando sabe-se que é uma pessoa próxima, tipo "E aí!" ou "Fala!", e expressões parecidas, com e sem o nome do interlocutor.

Por exemplo, quando um amigo meu que tenho bastante contato e intimidade me liga, eu já atendo falando "E aí, cara! De boa?!"